# How to pass cli arguments to react craco?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, craco

I want to add a `bundle-analyzer` to my react app, when the developer runs `yarn analyze` which has been set in `package.json` as `"analyze": "craco build --analyze-only"`.

I did read the `craco`'s manual but didnt find any solution for this. my current config is as below:

```js
const progressBar = require('./progressBar.webpack.config');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer')
  .BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

module.exports = {
  reactScriptsVersion: 'react-scripts' /* (default value) */,
  webpack: {
    alias: {},
    plugins: {
      add: [progressBar()] /* An array of plugins */
    },
    configure: (webpackConfig, { env, paths }) => {
      if (env === 'production') {
        webpackConfig.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin());
      }
      return webpackConfig;
    }
  }
};
```

How can we pass the args to it?

Comment: Do you mean you want to read argument of `--analyze-only` in the configuration file?

Comment: @tmhao2005 Yes, I want to have access to it, So when this argument has been passed, do something in the ` configure: (webpackConfig, { env, paths }) => {}` section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `process.argv` to check the arguments, e.g:

```js
// craco.config.js
//...
module.exports = {
  // ...
  webpack: {
  //...
    configure: (webpackConfig, { env, paths }) => {
      if (process.argv.includes('--analyze-only'))
        webpackConfig.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin());

      return webpackConfig;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: AAh, thank you , the problem has been solved(I forgot that we could use `process.argv`, because we are using `nodejs`. So,everywhere we have an access to it). Thank you alot for reminding me this